# I am making a reusable terraform module for google_monitoring_alert_policy, and I am stuck as to the best way to modularize it

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform

I am recieving the following errors on running my tf code, it expects map in the lookup function, i am confused if the nested key/value pairs inside the conditions block should already not return a map?:

```
Error: Invalid function argument

  on modules/google_monitoring_alert_policy/monitoring_alert_policy.tf line 68, in resource "google_monitoring_alert_policy" "alert_policy":
  68:                     threshold_value      = lookup(condition_threshold.value, "threshold_value", null)
    |----------------
    | condition_threshold.value is "COMPARISON_GT"

Invalid value for "inputMap" parameter: lookup() requires a map as the first
argument.


Error: Invalid function argument

  on modules/google_monitoring_alert_policy/monitoring_alert_policy.tf line 68, in resource "google_monitoring_alert_policy" "alert_policy":
  68:                     threshold_value      = lookup(condition_threshold.value, "threshold_value", null)
    |----------------
    | condition_threshold.value is "60s"

Invalid value for "inputMap" parameter: lookup() requires a map as the first
argument.


Error: Invalid function argument

  on modules/google_monitoring_alert_policy/monitoring_alert_policy.tf line 68, in resource "google_monitoring_alert_policy" "alert_policy":
  68:                     threshold_value      = lookup(condition_threshold.value, "threshold_value", null)
    |----------------
    | condition_threshold.value is "metric.type=\"compute.googleapis.com/instance/disk/write_bytes_count\" AND resource.type=\"gce_instance\""

Invalid value for "inputMap" parameter: lookup() requires a map as the first
argument.


Error: Invalid function argument

  on modules/google_monitoring_alert_policy/monitoring_alert_policy.tf line 69, in resource "google_monitoring_alert_policy" "alert_policy":
  69:                     denominator_filter   = lookup(condition_threshold.value, "denominator_filter", null)
    |----------------
    | condition_threshold.value is "COMPARISON_GT"

Invalid value for "inputMap" parameter: lookup() requires a map as the first
argument.


Error: Invalid function argument

  on modules/google_monitoring_alert_policy/monitoring_alert_policy.tf line 69, in resource "google_monitoring_alert_policy" "alert_policy":
  69:                     denominator_filter   = lookup(condition_threshold.value, "denominator_filter", null)
    |----------------
    | condition_threshold.value is "60s"

Invalid value for "inputMap" parameter: lookup() requires a map as the first
argument.


Error: Invalid function argument

  on modules/google_monitoring_alert_policy/monitoring_alert_policy.tf line 69, in resource "google_monitoring_alert_policy" "alert_policy":
  69:                     denominator_filter   = lookup(condition_threshold.value, "denominator_filter", null)
    |----------------
    | condition_threshold.value is "metric.type=\"compute.googleapis.com/instance/disk/write_bytes_count\" AND resource.type=\"gce_instance\""

Invalid value for "inputMap" parameter: lookup() requires a map as the first
argument.


Error: Unsupported attribute

  on modules/google_monitoring_alert_policy/monitoring_alert_policy.tf line 70, in resource "google_monitoring_alert_policy" "alert_policy":
  70:                     duration             = condition_threshold.value.duration
    |----------------
    | condition_threshold.value is object with 2 attributes

This object does not have an attribute named "duration".


Error: Unsupported attribute

  on modules/google_monitoring_alert_policy/monitoring_alert_policy.tf line 70, in resource "google_monitoring_alert_policy" "alert_policy":
  70:                     duration             = condition_threshold.value.duration
    |----------------
    | condition_threshold.value is "COMPARISON_GT"

This value does not have any attributes.


Error: Unsupported attribute

  on modules/google_monitoring_alert_policy/monitoring_alert_policy.tf line 70, in resource "google_monitoring_alert_policy" "alert_policy":
  70:                     duration             = condition_threshold.value.duration
    |----------------
    | condition_threshold.value is "60s"

This value does not have any attributes.


Error: Unsupported attribute

  on modules/google_monitoring_alert_policy/monitoring_alert_policy.tf line 70, in resource "google_monitoring_alert_policy" "alert_policy":
  70:                     duration             = condition_threshold.value.duration
    |----------------
    | condition_threshold.value is "metric.type=\"compute.googleapis.com/instance/disk/write_bytes_count\" AND resource.type=\"gce_instance\""

This value does not have any attributes.


Error: Unsupported attribute

  on modules/google_monitoring_alert_policy/monitoring_alert_policy.tf line 71, in resource "google_monitoring_alert_policy" "alert_policy":
  71:                     comparison           = condition_threshold.value.comparison
    |----------------
    | condition_threshold.value is object with 2 attributes

This object does not have an attribute named "comparison".


Error: Unsupported attribute

  on modules/google_monitoring_alert_policy/monitoring_alert_policy.tf line 71, in resource "google_monitoring_alert_policy" "alert_policy":
  71:                     comparison           = condition_threshold.value.comparison
    |----------------
    | condition_threshold.value is "COMPARISON_GT"

This value does not have any attributes.


Error: Unsupported attribute

  on modules/google_monitoring_alert_policy/monitoring_alert_policy.tf line 71, in resource "google_monitoring_alert_policy" "alert_policy":
  71:                     comparison           = condition_threshold.value.comparison
    |----------------
    | condition_threshold.value is "60s"

This value does not have any attributes.


Error: Unsupported attribute

  on modules/google_monitoring_alert_policy/monitoring_alert_policy.tf line 71, in resource "google_monitoring_alert_policy" "alert_policy":
  71:                     comparison           = condition_threshold.value.comparison
    |----------------
    | condition_threshold.value is "metric.type=\"compute.googleapis.com/instance/disk/write_bytes_count\" AND resource.type=\"gce_instance\""

This value does not have any attributes.


Error: Invalid function argument

  on modules/google_monitoring_alert_policy/monitoring_alert_policy.tf line 72, in resource "google_monitoring_alert_policy" "alert_policy":
  72:                     filter               = lookup(condition_threshold.value, "filter", null)
    |----------------
    | condition_threshold.value is "COMPARISON_GT"

Invalid value for "inputMap" parameter: lookup() requires a map as the first
argument.


Error: Invalid function argument

  on modules/google_monitoring_alert_policy/monitoring_alert_policy.tf line 72, in resource "google_monitoring_alert_policy" "alert_policy":
  72:                     filter               = lookup(condition_threshold.value, "filter", null)
    |----------------
    | condition_threshold.value is "60s"

Invalid value for "inputMap" parameter: lookup() requires a map as the first
argument.


Error: Invalid function argument

  on modules/google_monitoring_alert_policy/monitoring_alert_policy.tf line 72, in resource "google_monitoring_alert_policy" "alert_policy":
  72:                     filter               = lookup(condition_threshold.value, "filter", null)
    |----------------
    | condition_threshold.value is "metric.type=\"compute.googleapis.com/instance/disk/write_bytes_count\" AND resource.type=\"gce_instance\""

Invalid value for "inputMap" parameter: lookup() requires a map as the first
argument.


Error: Invalid function argument

  on modules/google_monitoring_alert_policy/monitoring_alert_policy.tf line 75, in resource "google_monitoring_alert_policy" "alert_policy":
  75:                         for_each = lookup(condition_threshold.value, "denominator_aggregations", [])
    |----------------
    | condition_threshold.value is "COMPARISON_GT"

Invalid value for "inputMap" parameter: lookup() requires a map as the first
argument.


Error: Invalid function argument

  on modules/google_monitoring_alert_policy/monitoring_alert_policy.tf line 75, in resource "google_monitoring_alert_policy" "alert_policy":
  75:                         for_each = lookup(condition_threshold.value, "denominator_aggregations", [])
    |----------------
    | condition_threshold.value is "60s"

Invalid value for "inputMap" parameter: lookup() requires a map as the first
argument.


Error: Invalid function argument

  on modules/google_monitoring_alert_policy/monitoring_alert_policy.tf line 75, in resource "google_monitoring_alert_policy" "alert_policy":
  75:                         for_each = lookup(condition_threshold.value, "denominator_aggregations", [])
    |----------------
    | condition_threshold.value is "metric.type=\"compute.googleapis.com/instance/disk/write_bytes_count\" AND resource.type=\"gce_instance\""

Invalid value for "inputMap" parameter: lookup() requires a map as the first
argument.


Error: Invalid function argument

  on modules/google_monitoring_alert_policy/monitoring_alert_policy.tf line 86, in resource "google_monitoring_alert_policy" "alert_policy":
  86:                         for_each = lookup(condition_threshold.value, "trigger", [])
    |----------------
    | condition_threshold.value is "COMPARISON_GT"

Invalid value for "inputMap" parameter: lookup() requires a map as the first
argument.


Error: Invalid function argument

  on modules/google_monitoring_alert_policy/monitoring_alert_policy.tf line 86, in resource "google_monitoring_alert_policy" "alert_policy":
  86:                         for_each = lookup(condition_threshold.value, "trigger", [])
    |----------------
    | condition_threshold.value is "60s"

Invalid value for "inputMap" parameter: lookup() requires a map as the first
argument.


Error: Invalid function argument

  on modules/google_monitoring_alert_policy/monitoring_alert_policy.tf line 86, in resource "google_monitoring_alert_policy" "alert_policy":
  86:                         for_each = lookup(condition_threshold.value, "trigger", [])
    |----------------
    | condition_threshold.value is "metric.type=\"compute.googleapis.com/instance/disk/write_bytes_count\" AND resource.type=\"gce_instance\""

Invalid value for "inputMap" parameter: lookup() requires a map as the first
argument.


Error: Invalid function argument

  on modules/google_monitoring_alert_policy/monitoring_alert_policy.tf line 94, in resource "google_monitoring_alert_policy" "alert_policy":
  94:                         for_each = lookup(condition_threshold.value, "aggregations", [])
    |----------------
    | condition_threshold.value is "COMPARISON_GT"

Invalid value for "inputMap" parameter: lookup() requires a map as the first
argument.


Error: Invalid function argument

  on modules/google_monitoring_alert_policy/monitoring_alert_policy.tf line 94, in resource "google_monitoring_alert_policy" "alert_policy":
  94:                         for_each = lookup(condition_threshold.value, "aggregations", [])
    |----------------
    | condition_threshold.value is "60s"

Invalid value for "inputMap" parameter: lookup() requires a map as the first
argument.


Error: Invalid function argument

  on modules/google_monitoring_alert_policy/monitoring_alert_policy.tf line 94, in resource "google_monitoring_alert_policy" "alert_policy":
  94:                         for_each = lookup(condition_threshold.value, "aggregations", [])
    |----------------
    | condition_threshold.value is "metric.type=\"compute.googleapis.com/instance/disk/write_bytes_count\" AND resource.type=\"gce_instance\""

Invalid value for "inputMap" parameter: lookup() requires a map as the first
argument.
```

my tf code is the following:

```
resource "google_monitoring_alert_policy" "alert_policy" {
  display_name          = var.display_name
  combiner              = var.combiner
  enabled               = var.enabled
  user_labels           = var.user_labels
  project               = var.project
  notification_channels = var.notification_channels

  dynamic "conditions" {
    for_each = length(keys(var.conditions)) == 0 ? [] : [var.conditions]
    content {
      display_name = conditions.value.display_name


      dynamic "condition_absent" {

        for_each = lookup(conditions.value, "condition_absent", [])

        content {
          duration = condition_absent.value.duration
          filter   = lookup(condition_absent.value, "filter", null)

          dynamic "aggregations" {

            for_each = lookup(condition_absent.value, "aggregations", [])
            content {
              per_series_aligner   = lookup(aggregations.value, "per_series_aligner", null)
              group_by_fields      = lookup(aggregations.value, "group_by_fields", null)
              alignment_period     = lookup(aggregations.value, "alignment_period", null)
              cross_series_reducer = lookup(aggregations.value, "cross_series_reducer", null)
            }
          }

          dynamic "trigger" {

            for_each = lookup(condition_absent.value, "trigger", [])
            content {
              percent = lookup(trigger.value, "percent", null)
              count   = lookup(trigger.value, "count", null)
            }
          }
        }
      }

      dynamic "condition_monitoring_query_language" {

        for_each = lookup(conditions.value, "condition_monitoring_query_language", [])
        content {
          duration = condition_monitoring_query_language.value.duration
          query    = condition_monitoring_query_language.value.query

          dynamic "trigger" {
            for_each = lookup(condition_monitoring_query_language.value, "trigger", [])
            content {
              percent = lookup(trigger.value, "percent", null)
              count   = lookup(trigger.value, "count", null)
            }
          }
        }
      }


      dynamic "condition_threshold" {
        for_each = lookup(conditions.value, "condition_threshold", [])
        content {
          threshold_value    = lookup(condition_threshold.value, "threshold_value", null)
          denominator_filter = lookup(condition_threshold.value, "denominator_filter", null)
          duration           = condition_threshold.value.duration
          comparison         = condition_threshold.value.comparison
          filter             = lookup(condition_threshold.value, "filter", null)

          dynamic "denominator_aggregations" {
            for_each = lookup(condition_threshold.value, "denominator_aggregations", [])
            content {
              per_series_aligner   = lookup(denominator_aggregations.value, "per_series_aligner", null)
              group_by_fields      = lookup(denominator_aggregations.value, "group_by_fields", null)
              alignment_period     = lookup(denominator_aggregations.value, "alignment_period", null)
              cross_series_reducer = lookup(denominator_aggregations.value, "cross_series_reducer", null)

            }
          }

          dynamic "trigger" {
            for_each = lookup(condition_threshold.value, "trigger", [])
            content {
              percent = lookup(trigger.value, "percent", null)
              count   = lookup(trigger.value, "count", null)
            }
          }

          dynamic "aggregations" {
            for_each = lookup(condition_threshold.value, "aggregations", [])
            content {
              per_series_aligner   = lookup(aggregations.value, "per_series_aligner", null)
              group_by_fields      = lookup(aggregations.value, "group_by_fields", null)
              alignment_period     = lookup(aggregations.value, "alignment_period", null)
              cross_series_reducer = lookup(aggregations.value, "cross_series_reducer", null)

            }
          }

        }

      }

      dynamic "condition_matched_log" {
        for_each = lookup(conditions.value, "condition_matched_log", [])
        content {
          filter           = lookup(condition_matched_log.value, "filter", null)
          label_extractors = lookup(condition_matched_log.value, "label_extractors", null)


        }
      }
    }
  }

  dynamic "alert_strategy" {
    for_each = length(keys(var.alert_strategy)) == 0 ? [] : [var.alert_strategy]

    content {

      auto_close = lookup(alert_strategy.value, "auto_close", null)

      dynamic "notification_rate_limit" {
        for_each = lookup(alert_strategy.value, "notification_rate_limit", [])
        content {
          period = lookup(notification_rate_limit.value, "period", null)
        }
      }
    }
  }

  dynamic "documentation" {
    for_each = length(keys(var.documentation)) == 0 ? [] : [var.documentation]

    content {
      content   = lookup(documentation.value, "content", null)
      mime_type = lookup(documentation.value, "mime_type", null)
    }
  }
}
```

my variables.tf file is the following:
// https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/monitoring_alert_policy
/*
Meta variables
*/

```
variable "create_resource" {
  description = "Specify wheter or not to create the resource."
  type        = bool
  default     = true
}

variable "project" {
  description = "The ID of the project in which the resource belongs. If it is not provided, the provider project is used."
  type        = string
  default     = null
}

variable "name" {
  description = "The identifier of this resource."
  type        = string
}

/*
  Resource variables
*/

variable "display_name" {
  description = "A short name or phrase used to identify the policy in dashboards, notifications, and incidents."
  type        = string
}

variable "combiner" {
  description = "How to combine the results of multiple conditions to determine if an incident should be opened. Possible values are AND, OR, and AND_WITH_MATCHING_RESOURCE"
  type        = string
  default     = ""
}

variable "conditions" {
  description = "A list of conditions for the policy. The conditions are combined by AND or OR according to the combiner field. If the combined conditions evaluate to true, then an incident is created. A policy can have from one to six conditions."
  type        = any
  default     = {}
}

variable "enabled" {
  description = "Whether or not the policy is enabled. The default is true"
  type        = bool
  default     = true
}

variable "alert_strategy" {
  description = "Control over how this alert policy's notification channels are notified."
  type        = any
  default     = {}
}

variable "user_labels" {
  description = "This field is intended to be used for organizing and identifying the AlertPolicy objects"
  type        = map(string)
  default     = {}
}

variable "documentation" {
  description = "Documentation that is included with notifications and incidents related to this policy."
  type        = any
  default     = {}
}

variable "notification_channels" {
  description = "list of notification channels"
  type        = list(string)
  default     = []
}
```

and in the main module i am using the module as follows:

```
module logging_alert_policy {
  source = "./modules/google_monitoring_alert_policy/"
  display_name = "My Alert Policy"
  name         = "test_policy_1"
  combiner     = "OR"
  conditions   = {
    
    display_name = "test condition"
    condition_threshold ={
      filter     = "metric.type=\"compute.googleapis.com/instance/disk/write_bytes_count\" AND resource.type=\"gce_instance\""
      duration   = "60s"
      comparison = "COMPARISON_GT"
      aggregations ={
        alignment_period   = "60s"
        per_series_aligner = "ALIGN_RATE"
      }
    }
  }

  user_labels = {
    foo = "bar"
  }
}
```

Comment: The declaration and definition of `var.conditions` seems important to understanding the effect of this configuration. Could you edit your question to include both the `variable "conditions"` block and the value you've assigned to that variable?

Comment: Were you able to solve this ?